# How to identify the current user when redirected from an auth0 rule

Tags: authentication, auth0

My authentication flow is as follows...

1. User visits my site and clicks login.
2. They are redirected to mydomain.auth0.com (or something like that), where they are prompted to login using either a username or password or a social provider e.g. Google.
3. Following the user's login, I run a custom rule in Auth0 to detect if they are a new user. If `yes` I now want to redirect them to a custom page to collect some additional data. I do this my implementing the following in the rule:

   function (user, context, callback) {
     context.redirect = {
           url: 'http://www.example.com/profile'
       };

   callback(null, user, context);
   }

This redirects the user back to my site adding a `?state=xyz...` to the query string.

However, at this point I don't have a token or id token and seemingly no way to identify the user.

The example given at Auth0 talks about using this flow to force a user to update their password on login. However, for this to work there has to be some way to identify the user on the page they are redirected to.

What is the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from a Rule that redirects users to a post authentication registration page. Just pasting the section related to altering `context.redirect` since that is what you are asking about.

```
var hasPostRegistered = user.app_metadata && user.app_metadata.has_post_registered;

  // redirect to consent form if user has not yet consented
  if (!hasPostRegistered && context.protocol !== 'redirect-callback') {

    var auth0Domain = auth0.baseUrl.match(/([^:]*:\/\/)?([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/)[2];
    var userId = user.user_id;

    context.redirect = {
      url: configuration.REGISTRATION_FORM_URL +
      (configuration.REGISTRATION_FORM_URL.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') +
      'auth0_domain=' + encodeURIComponent(auth0Domain) +
      '&user_id=' + encodeURIComponent(userId)
    };

  }
```

Notice how the `user_id` is tagged on as a query param.

Note also, you can self-sign a JWT token inside a Rule, and send that to your redirect endpoint, which in turn can be configured to read / verify that JWT Token as a way to secure the redirection.